# RSForm! integration with CiviCRM

Tags: joomla

A friend is using the RSForm! Pro extension with Joomla and wants to gather volunteer signup information and port the data to CiviCRM. Does anyone have any experience with doing this? What is involved. I do not find any reference to this product on StackExchange and a web search doesn't turn up much.

Answer (score 1):

RSForm! Pro is made by RSJoomla (rsjoomla.com) and has the ability to post data to external (to Joomla) databases. This article at their site may help: https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/custom-scripting/silent-post.html